# Do I need single integrals, multiple integral or an iterated interval?

Tags: integration

I am new to integrals and I am struggling to understand if I need to use a single integral, a multiple integral or an iterated interval in the situation that I am facing.

Consider that you have a table where in the columns you have values of $\tau$ ranging from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. There is an infinite number of such columns. Furthermore, the rows of the table hold the values of $T$, which range from $0$ to $\infty$. There is also an infinite number of rows.

The value in each cell of the table is determined by the following formula:

$$
\frac{e^-{\frac{\left[ln {T} - \left(\beta-\tau\right)\right]^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$

What I want to have as a result is the sum of each column of the table. I don't want to have a sum of these sums, but instead I want to have a function that takes $\tau$ as the input and as the output it returns the sum of all the values in the table in the column which represents the chosen value of $\tau$.

What is the function that I am looking for? How does its formula look like? I am really new to integrals and I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Let us simplify your issue : you have in each cell a certain value $f(T,\tau)$ given by your expression where $T$ is the row index and $\tau$ the column index. It is hard for me to understand if it is a discrete or a continuous issue. Maybe you have infinitesimal increments ? If such is the case "summing along a row" till a certain $T_0$ can be written : $\int_{T=-\infty}^{T_0} f(T,\tau)dT$ **for a fixed value of $\tau$.**

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for your reply. This is a continuous issue and not a discrete one. So in that case, yes, I think I have infinitesimal increments of $T$ and also of $\tau$. I would just also like to clarify if "summing along rows" means the same as "column sum" - the sum of all values that appear in a certain column?

Comment: @JeanMarie Furthermore, the problem is that I don't want to sum up to some $T_0$, but for all possible values of $T$, which range from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Answer to last question: this is what is meant by my $T_0$ : $T_0$ is meant as **any** stopping value for the summation. Answer to the previous comment: No, the column summation is $\int_{\tau=-\infty}^{\tau_0}f(T,\tau)d \tau$ this time fo a fixed value of $T$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, I don't understand. If $T$ is the row index and $\tau$ is the column index, and let's say that I want to sum all the values in the first column. So all these values have the same value of $\tau$ because they are in the same column, and they have different $T$ because they go downwards from the top of the table to the bottom. So the column sums should be for a fixed value of $\tau$ and row sums should be for a fixed value of $T$

Comment: I may have switched at one time or another between $T$ and $\tau$ but the ideas I gave, (so I think!) are the right ones : in particular you have to introduce supplementary variables $T_0$ and $\tau_0$ in your partial integrations (integration with respect to one among the two variables).